# Copy file in C++ using fstream in binary mode

Tags: c++

Below is my function to copy file from source to destination

```
void CopyFile(const std::string& source, const std::string& destination)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(source.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!ifs.good())
        return;
    std::ofstream ofs(destination.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    const int bufferSize = 4;
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    std::streamoff streamSize = ifs.tellg();
    std::streamoff iteration = streamSize / bufferSize;
    int rem = streamSize % bufferSize;
    ifs.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    while (iteration > 0)
    {
        ifs.read(buffer, bufferSize);
        ofs.write(buffer, bufferSize);
        ifs.seekg(bufferSize, std::ios::cur);
        ofs.seekp(bufferSize, std::ios::cur);
        --iteration;
    }
    ifs.read(buffer, rem);
    ofs.write(buffer, rem);
    ifs.close();
    ofs.close();
}
```

other approach where i open file in non binary mode working for me but not this one. what am i missing here?

Comment: What is the output are you getting?

Comment: There's way more efficient ways, or idiomatic, especially using `ofs << ifs.rdbuf();`. If you're going to use buffered streams for such a job, at least make it easily-to-read.

Comment: Why bother working out the size of the file when you can just keep reading `bufferSize` chunks until [`ifs.gcount()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) returns a smaller size?

Comment: Also, the `seekg` and `seekp` are just wrong here, as `read` and `write` will also move the file positions. And a 4 byte buffer seems to be a bit small.

Comment: @Md Monjur UI Hasan   i was trying to copy jpg image file. but windows photo viewer says created file is corrupted.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh will this be efficient if file size is too big to hold in memory at once

Comment: @Ken Y-N   thanks that is working

Comment: @Bo Persson   looks like this was the problem. after removing seekg and seekp, it works. thanks

Comment: BTW, if you are on Windows, it already has a [builtin `CopyFile` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @bhawesh No it won't, but there's much more efficient ways using `CopyFile` on Windows, or using `open` and `read` with buffers of 4-32 KB on POSIX systems (avoids buffering, and let's you optimize a lot). Finally, all these options are way more idiomatic and less code than the above, and are still exception-safe. If you don't care about efficiency, `ofs << ifs.rdbuf();`  is a great option.